Angular 18: Interceptor Not Working After Upgrade from Angular 16
I am currently using Angular 18 for my application and my application is modular-based. Previously, my application was developed using Angular 16, but I have recently upgraded it to Angular 18. However, after the upgrade, I have encountered an issue where the interceptor in my application is no longer functioning as expected.
Here is my app-module code
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NZ_I18N, en_US } from 'ng-zorro-antd/i18n';
import { registerLocaleData, PathLocationStrategy, 
LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import en from '@angular/common/locales/en';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CommonLayoutComponent } from './layouts/common- 
layout/common-layout.component';
import { ThemeConstantService } from './shared/services/theme- 
constant.service';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthInterceptor } from './auth/services/auth- 
interceptor.service';
registerLocaleData(en);
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CommonLayoutComponent,
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
],
providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AuthInterceptor,
        multi: true,
    },
    {
        provide: NZ_I18N,
        useValue: en_US,
    },
    {
        provide: LocationStrategy,
        useClass: PathLocationStrategy
    },
    ThemeConstantService
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}


please share main.ts also app.component.ts

You are missing HttpClientModule / provideHttpClient()

@TauseefArshad only API calls made through http module of angular are intercepted, so  that might be the problem, add HttpClientModule to the providers array of the APP module and make a http call through http client which will get intercepted by interceptor AuthInterceptor
